# Sin valor al hacer un jquery.get() sobre un archivo json

Tags: jquery, json

tengo un api que devuelve un json cuyo formato es el siguiente:

```
{
"id": 255,
"texto": "En un lugar de la mancha",
"categories": []
}
```

Desde un html intento obtener una de las multiples frases de la api en la variable frase con el siguiente script para luego sustituir las cabeceras  con la frase.

```
<script>
jQuery.get("direccionapi", (Response) => {
    var frase = Response.texto;
    $('h2').text(frase);
})
</script>
```

No obtengo nigún tipo de resultado no cambia el valor de la cabecera h2. Pero si miro la consola de firefox me aparece que si ha realizado el GET. En "Response payload" aparece el json de la api.

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ¿Tienes un elemento `h2` en el HTML? Prueba o poner uno así: `<h2 id="test"></h2>`. Y en el código JS: `$( "#test" ).html( Response.texto );` De paso, prueba si funciona esa parte del código: `alert(Response.texto);`

Answer (score 0):

La funcion de flecha => devuelve un array de elementos.
Podrías acceder al primer elemento pero no es lo recomendable, por lo cual la otra opción es usar la función común

```
jQuery.get("direccionapi", function(Response) {
    var frase = Response.texto;
    $('h2').text(frase);
});
```

Saludos!